# Plotting high frequency financial correlation in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, time-series

I have two columns in Csv, One is date and other is correlation value and total data points are 2000. and the date format is %m/%d/%y. 
but due to so many values, the particular date for any particular day correlation value is not visible on the plot and without date, the plot has no meaning.
Can anybody edit my code so that few of the dates are visible on the x-axis so that some references can be drawn from the plot with respect to the month and year?
the link to the csv is:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Bpy90NOVf3nIMVxVhORtDoK_FpyAvfO6/view?usp=sharing

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = pd.read_csv('BSE_NYSA_DCC.csv')
len(data)
s=data.loc[0:2088,'Date']
t=data.loc[0:2088,'corr']
fix,axes=plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(20,10))


axes.plot(s,t,linewidth=5,marker='*',markersize=20)
axes.set_xlabel('Date')
axes.set_ylabel('Daily_CORR')
axes.set_title('BSE_NYSA_DCC')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your data, the "Date" column doesn't use the same delimiter for all the rows, so the `read_csv` function doesn't parse this column as the date datatype. However, you can tell the function this is a date column by using the `parse_dates` argument.

```
data = pd.read_csv('BSE_NYSA_DCC.csv', parse_dates=['Date'])
```

Also, your linewidth and markersize are very big, you can change them to smaller values so people can better view your plot.